# My Backbone app flashes "white" screen because I removed the view first before starting a new one

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I had zombie problems with Backbone. (http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

So, I followed that tutorial and it solved all my problems.

Basically, the tutorial says that I need to close a view first (`this.close()` and `this.unbind()`) before I start a new view.

However, after following this tutorial, side effect occurred. When I do "close", my application deletes the "el" and there is nothing on the page (the screen is white).  When the new view is rendered, there is content again.

Previously, there was no white flash at all because nothing was removed. (new render template replaces old one).  The site seemed faster before, but now there is a flash.

Comment: Let me know if my suggestion works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not render the view first before closing the old one:

1. Render new view
2. Close old view

Comment: closing the old one using this.remove() destroys the el, which removes all the html

Comment: Have you considered using Backbone's Router?